# Exactly position html elements above svg

Tags: html, svg

I have an HTML page with an SVG in it. I know want to place HTML elements (input elements to be exact) above the SVG programmatically.

I have the desired positions of the elements in percent of the SVG width and height.

How do I get the elements to that position?

One Idea of mine was, to have a div around the SVG with exactly the same dimensions than I could do:

```
<div ...>
    <svg>...</svg>
    <input style="top:10%..."/>
    ...
</div>
```

But for this, the outer div would have to have the exact same dimensions as the SVG, and I do not know how to do that. The SVG has only a viewBox, no "width" and "height" attributes.

Comment: put the input elements inside foreignObject elements in the SVG and position the foreignObject elements as desired.

Comment: @RobertLongson Hey, that is a good Idea,  thanks. But unfortunately the data-structure I am given and I have to work with is given.And it is an SVG + input elements with percentage positions.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: relative;` to the "wrapper" and `position: absolute;` to the elements inside. Also, you need to set the size (width and height) to the wrapper to make the `%`-positions work inside.

```css
.wrap {
   position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.wrap input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="svg"></div><!-- just cheating the svg with bg-color -->
    <input type="text" style="top: 10%;" >
</div>
```